# Как правильно реализовать взаимосвязь между модулями приложения?

Tags: angularjs

Здравствуйте. Хочу переписать сайт на основе angular и уже в трех контроллерах начал путаться. Сделал три модуля, стало ориентироваться намного проще, но возник вопрос во взаимодействии модулей.

По логике, модуль должен иметь минимальную зависимость от всего приложения. Если его убрать полностью, то по идее не должно возникать никаких ошибок. Приложение не должно заметить его (модуля) отсутствие.

Сайт с огромным функционалом и еще планируется добавлять, поэтому модулей будет очень много. А сейчас у меня нету четкого понимания по взаимодействию.

Для управления приходится в родительском модуле (у которого прописаны зависимости от user и popup) прописывать $scope.blk; и точно так же прописать в модуле всплывающего окна. Я уверен, что это не самый удачный вариант. Когда модулей будет много, то такие связи будет невозможно отследить, а запоминать не есть хорошо.

Есть предположение, что взаимодействие можно реализовать через конфиги, либо для каждого модуля писать сервис взаимодействия со своим API

**UPD:**
Вот такое решение получилось. Модуль небольшой, поэтому с легкостью им можно управлять через фабрику.

хтмл:

```
<div ng-controller="popupCtrl">
    <div class="opacity" ng-show="pop.api.visible"></div>
    <div class="pop" ng-show="pop.api.visible">
        <div class="close" ng-click="pop.Out()"></div>
        <div class="title" ng-bind="pop.api.title"></div>
        <div class="msg" ng-bind="pop.api.msg"></div>
        <div class="text" ng-include="pop.In()"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

js:

```
    var popup = angular.module('popup', []);

popup.controller('popupCtrl', ['$scope', 'popupFctr', function($scope, popupFctr){

    $scope.pop = popupFctr;
    // закрываем popup
    $scope.pop.Out = function(){
        $scope.pop.api.visible = false;
        $scope.pop.api.file = 'popup/views/pop.html';
        $scope.pop.api.title = '';
        $scope.pop.api.msg = '';
    };
    // открываем popup
    $scope.pop.In = function(){
        if($scope.pop.api.visible === true){
            return $scope.pop.api.modulesdir + $scope.pop.api.file;
        }
    };

}]);

popup.factory('popupFctr', function(){
    return {
        api:{
            visible:false
            ,title:""
            ,msg:""
            ,modulesdir:""
            ,file:'popup/views/pop.html'
        }
    };
});
```

И есть модуль user, из которого настроено управление всплывающим окном

```
    $scope.getPassrec = function(){
        popupFctr.api.file = 'user/views/passrec.html';
        popupFctr.api.title = 'Восстановление доступа';
        popupFctr.api.visible = true;
    };
```

Comment: а в чем смысл этого blk?

Comment: @Grundy, пока я только так придумал передать данные из модуля user в модуль popup

Comment: как-то все слишком запутано. Стоит посмотреть пример с попапами в том же https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/